# Turan density results for 4- or 5- graphs

Tags: graph-theory, extremal-combinatorics, extremal-graph-theory

I was wondering if there are results for Turan densities of 4- or 5-graphs (hypergraphs). I am aware of several surveys of hypergraph Turan densities (due to Pikhurko, Keevash), but these mainly focus on 3-graphs.

I am only aware of several results for 4- or 5- graphs (or higher-order hypergraphs in general); apologies in advance if I misattribute any results:

Markstrom has shown the Turan density in graphs forbidding $K_{5}^{4}$ is upper bounded by ~0.736. Sidorenko has shown a lower bound of $\frac{11}{16}$, which is conjectured to be exact.

de Caen and Sidorenko have shown that the Turan $(K_{r+1}^{r})^{-}$-density in graphs forbidding $K_{r+1}^{r}$ is upper bounded by $1 - \frac{1}{r}$ (here I use $(K_{r+1}^{r})^{-}$ to denote $K_{r+1}^{r}$ minus an edge). (I think de Caen also has a general upper and lower bound for $K_{s}^{r}$.) Lu and Zhao tighten this density in the case where $r$ is even.

But what I am looking for is Turan densities for the "stranger cases". I know for 3-graphs there are lower bounds for many weird Turan densities, like $\pi(K_{4}^{-}, C_{5})$, or $\pi(K_{4}^{-}, C_{5}, F_{3,2})$ (and here I am mostly referring to the results in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1201.4326)). Is there anything similar for 4- or 5-graphs?

Comment: I met [Oleg Pikhurko](https://warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/maths/people/staff/oleg_pikhurko/) a week ago, at [our seminar](http://www.math.lviv.ua/seminar/). I think you can try to greet him with yesterday’s Orthodox Easter and politely ask him your question.

Comment: Thanks. To my knowledge, there is little known about these numbers, and I am now working on improving the bounds I stated in the question, so this problem is less pressing to me now.